# Looking for subviewsDidChange delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mkmapview

I'm looking for some kind of delegate method that will be triggered when a subview is added to a view. I need this because the compass view on the iOS7 map is added to the mapview when it starts rotating (it is not there previously and unhidden). However when I try to manipulate the compass view in `regionWillChangeAnimated` it doesn't trigger until the user lets go of the map.

Basically I need anything along the lines of:
`subviewWasAdded`, `subviewsDidChange`, or anything like that.

**EDIT:** After taking Daij-Djan's suggestion, I made MPOMapView.m and MPOMapView.

```
#import "MPOMapView.h"

@implementation MPOMapView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    [super addSubview:view];

    [self moveCompass:&view];
}


- (void)moveCompass:(UIView **)view {

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
        return;
    }

    if(![*view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
        return;
    }

    //Gets here
    NSLog(@"Was the compass");

    float width = (*view).frame.size.width;
    float height = (*view).frame.size.height;

    (*view).frame = CGRectMake(40, self.frame.size.height - 50, width, height);

    //Frame doesn't change
    NSLog(@"Frame should change");
}

@end
```

The method is called, but the frame won't change. I've also tried:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    [super addSubview:view];

    [self moveCompass:view];
}


- (void)moveCompass:(UIView *)view {

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
        return;
    }

    if(![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
        return;
    }

    //Gets here
    NSLog(@"Was the compass");

    float width = view.frame.size.width;
    float height = view.frame.size.height;

    view.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.frame.size.height - 50, width, height);

    //Frame doesn't change
    NSLog(@"Frame should change");
}
```

but this doesn't work either. And lastly....

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    [super addSubview:[self movedCompass:view]];
}


- (UIView *)movedCompass:(UIView *)view {

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
        return view;
    }

    if(![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
        return view;
    }

    //Gets here
    NSLog(@"Was the compass");

    float width = view.frame.size.width;
    float height = view.frame.size.height;

    view.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.frame.size.height - 50, width, height);

    //Frame doesn't change
    NSLog(@"Frame should change");

    return view;
}
```

does not work either

Comment: @Mike_V did you manage to get your app accepted with your code accessing the MKCompassView private class that way? I need to do the same thing for a public application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such delegate.

BUT

all you can do is subclass MKMapView and implement insertSubview and addSubview and build your own solution.

BUT

see better way

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

                if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
                     return;
                }

    for(id view in self.subviews) {
                if(![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
                     continue;
                }

                [self moveCompass:view]];
    }
}

- (void)moveCompass:(UIView *)view {
    //Gets here
    NSLog(@"Was the compass");

    float width = view.frame.size.width;
    float height = view.frame.size.height;

    //view.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.frame.size.height - 50, width, height);
    view.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.bounds.size.height - 50, width, height);

}
```

Comment: I will try this out and accept the answer if ends up working out for us. Thanks!

Comment: ah I see what you wanna do :) please just save a pointer to the view in addSubview and implement layoutViews... Ill edit my code in a sec

Comment: edited.. you don't need to hook into `addSubview`. To change the frame do override `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Just need to change `if(![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
                     return;
                }` to `if(![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) {
            continue;
        }` and then it works perfectly!

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks for the answer, needed this! There is however no need to check systemVersion<7 because NSClassFromString(@"unknown") will not crash, nor will any of the code that follows if that 'if' statement is removed. And I would place [self moveCompass:view] into the if statement above it and ofcoz have the if statement read: if([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]), then remove the continue statement. Just seems like too much unnecessary code. I hope I'm not missing something, just like to understand what I'm doing before walking away.

Answer (score 2):

Daij-Djan has posted the correct answer, credit to him!

This is just an improvement on what I feel is too much code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for(id view in self.subviews) 
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]) 
            [self moveCompass:view]];
    }
}

- (void)moveCompass:(UIView *)view 
{
    //change compass frame as shown by Daij-Djan
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, buy you could try using Key Value Observing with the mapview's `camera`, which has a `heading` property.

Comment: Tried `[self.mapView.camera addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"heading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];` and `- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
        NSLog(@"Key path: %@", keyPath);
}` but nothing is ever printed

Comment: Thanks for trying. Too bad it didn't work out, but good to know that there's no KVO on the map camera.